# Updating multiple documents with different ids in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

Right now I am updating multiple subdocuments with

```
var positions = [
  { id: '1', position: { x: 0, y: 0 } },
  ...
];

positions.forEach(element => {
  Model.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: modelId, 'elements._id': element.id }, {
    $set: {
      'elements.$.position': element.position
    }
  });
});
```

but is it possible to call the database in only 1 call?

## Edit

I could, for instance, do

```
Model.findById(modelId).then(model => {
  positions.forEach(element => {
    const doc = model.elements.id(element.id);
    doc.position = element.position;
  });
  model.save();
});
```

but would it have better performance?

## Edit 2

I tried implementing what you suggested, but nothing happens.

I have debugged a bit, and it seems nothing is happening after the first line of code:

```
console.log('this is printed')
const batch = ModelName.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
console.log('this is _not_ printed')
```

Do you know what can cause this? I get no error message.

## Edit 3

```
var batch = ModelName.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

positions.forEach(element => {
  batch.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: modelId, 'elements._id': element.id }, {
    $set: {
      'elements.$.position': element.position
    }
  });
});

batch.execute().then(() => {
  console.log('success');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: you cannot make batch a constant. it needs to be mutable since we are adding operations to the batch procedure. Make it a variable.

Comment: It doesn't work with `var batch = ModelName.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();` either.

Comment: please post your code. Are you adding to the batch operation like my example? Are you calling `execute()` as my example?

Comment: Yes I do. See my updated question

Answer (score -1):

Certainly, you can do an unordered bulk operation. Which makes only one call to the database server. Yes, this has significant performance improvements over the former.

```
var batch = Model.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

var positions = [
    { nodeId: '1', position: { x: 0, y: 0 } },
    { nodeId: '2', position: { x: 3, y: 4 } },
];

positions.forEach(el => {
    batch.findOneAndUpdate({<YOUR STUFF>});
});

batch.execute().then(console.log);
```

[MongoDB NodeJS Driver Documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#initializeUnorderedBulkOp)

Comment: Is this the same as my second example where I only call `parent.save()` once?

Comment: no, because you are calling a `find` then a `save` thus making 2 db calls. This makes only 1.